# ifsream::readsome issue. Buffer exceeds

Tags: c++, buffer

I have investigated that method `ifstream::readsome(buf, size)` doesn't read all bytes if there isn't enough space in buffer. Exmample:

I have buffer: 4096 bytes. Offset from the file begin: 6 bytes. 
I call  `ifstream::readsome(buf, 4097)`.

The result of function is 4090. So if i want to read rest seven bytes I must to call

`ifstream::readsome(buf + 4090, 7)`.

And the question is: why is this function implemented in such way? I don't see any problems to handle buffer exceeding inside method `ifstream::readsome(buf, size)`.

Compiler: MSVC 11 (VS 2012)

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's the meaning of `readsome`.  It does *not* invoke
any of the virtual functions on the `streambuf` (which may
block); it is defined to return *only* the characters currently
in the buffer.

If you need more, then you should use `read`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not guaranteed, that your buffer will always be completely filled, so it might occur that you really just 4090 bytes instead of 4906 bytes.

From `cplusplus.com`

---

Read data available in buffer
 Extracts up to n characters from the stream and stores them in the array pointed by s, stopping as soon as the internal buffer kept by the associated stream buffer object (if any) runs out of characters, even if the end-of-file has not yet been reached.

The function is meant to be used to read data from certain types of asynchronous sources that may eventually wait for more characters, since it stops extracting characters as soon as the internal buffer is exhausted, avoiding potential delays.

Note that this function relies on internals of the particular stream buffer object associated to the stream whose behavior is mostly implementation-defined for standard classes.

Internally, the function accesses the input sequence by first constructing a sentry object (with noskipws set to true). Then (if good), it checks how many characters are currently available at the associated stream buffer object by calling its member function in_avail and extracts up to that many characters by calling sbumpc (or sgetc). Finally, it destroys the sentry object before returning.

The number of characters successfully read and stored by this function can be accessed by calling member gcount.

---

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/readsome/) for the article.